# Powershell: Select-String & Regular Expression

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-scripting

Bit of backstory as to why I am using regex in the first place:

I am working on a script for multiple clients that will be integrated into our fortnightly maintenance. The script is set to change the date of a scheduled task to the date the script is run, but not adjust the time.

Now that in itself is easy, however we have multiple clients with multiple different times that the task will run, and I do not want to have to manually update every script for each client, because if we ever update the script, we would have to manually update it for everyone.

So I am resorting to Select-String and Regex to resolve the problem.

Onto the problem:

I am running the below code

```
$test = Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "Scheduled Shutdown"
$test | Select-String -inputobject {$_.LastRunTime} -Pattern '..:..:..'
```

Which outputs the below

```
10/01/2019 18:30:00
```

However I only want the actual time string, not the date as well.
No matter what I change the pattern to, I cannot get it to specifically output to the time only.

I was using a website called RegExr to test with as well as running the script.

Comment: Have you tried `$test.Lastruntime.ToString('HH:mm:ss')` It's an actual `DateTime` ... you should not use regex in this case I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$test = Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "Scheduled Shutdown"
(($test | Select-String -inputobject {$_.LastRunTime} -Pattern '..:..:..') -split ' ')[-1]
```

split the time string at a space, then choose the time

Comment: While this works, I'm baffled OP doesn't simply use the suggestion made by @Olaf. This is overcomplicating things to an extreme. A simple `(Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "Scheduled Shutdown").LastRunTime.ToString('HH:mm:ss')` would do.